# PR2 Segfaults Gazebo World

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have been trying to get the pr2 simulator up and running but I seem to be having issues with segfaults that have something to do with pr2_no_controllers.launch.

I ran the following,

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch 

roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_no_controllers.launch
```

I went into the launch file to see what I could comment out and see when segfaults stop.  It seemed to be when the pr2_description is pushed to the robot_description.

```
  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo-->
  <node name="spawn_pr2_model" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE)
 -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model pr2 -ros_namespace /gazebo" respawn="false" output="screen" />
```

I also ran,

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds debug.launch
```

and bt after (gdb)

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/8675ab3497ba3637428494164e1b9fe3

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4313/pr2-segfaults-gazebo-world/) by [ncr7](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/458/ncr7/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So Apparently if this happens it means something didn't install correctly.  It seemed to about get loaded before, but crash right before it finished loading the PR2.  Basically the only thing not loaded would be the arms.  I think it was a problem with the cameras loading.
I uninstalled everything having to do with ROS and Gazebo and reinstalled.  I am not sure what I did differently than any other time I reinstalled Groovy, I reinstalled several times, eventually it seemed to do the trick though... a bit odd.

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/458/ncr7/) with karma: 38 on 2013-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0